# JS: Filter array of objects by array, when object key is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects that look similar to the following:

```
let array = [
{
id: 1,
name: Foo,
tools: [{id:3, toolname: Jaw},{id:1, toolname: Law}]
},
{
id: 2,
name: Boo,
tools: [{id:2, toolname: Caw}]
},
{
id: 3,
name: Loo,
tools: [{id:3, toolname: Jaw}, {id:4, toolname: Maw}]
}
]
```

I am trying to filter objects from the above array using something similar to `includes` against an existing array which looks like the following:

```
let secondarray = ['Jaw', 'Taw']
```

How would I return a list of objects which has a tool named within the second array?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with the `tools` inside [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let array = [{id: 1,name: 'Foo',tools: [{id: 3,toolname: 'Jaw'}, {id: 1,toolname: 'Law'}]},{id: 2,name: 'Boo',tools: [{id: 2,toolname: 'Caw'}]},{id: 3,name: 'Loo',tools: [{id: 3,toolname: 'Jaw'}, {id: 4,toolname: 'Maw'}]}]
let secondarray = ['Jaw', 'Taw']

let filtered = array.filter(item => item.tools.some(obj => secondarray.includes(obj.toolname)))

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for- nice and concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might use something like this:

```js
let array = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Foo',
        tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 1, toolname: 'Law' }]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Boo',
        tools: [{ id: 2, toolname: 'Caw' }]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Loo',
        tools: [{ id: 3, toolname: 'Jaw' }, { id: 4, toolname: 'Maw' }]
    }
]
let secondarray = ['Jaw', 'Taw']
let filteredArray = array.filter(ch => {
    let controlArray = ch.tools.map(t => t.toolname);
    return secondarray.some(t => controlArray.includes(t));
});
console.log(filteredArray);
/**
which returns 

[ { id: 1, name: 'Foo', tools: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Loo', tools: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]

*/
```

Comment: This is a great method as well- thank you very much!!